# How to drop DB indices before bulk loading in seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my rails app I have a seeds.rb script which inserts lots of records. In fact I'm trying to load 16 million of them. It's taking a long time.

One thing I wanted to try to speed this up, is to **drop the table indices and re-add them afterwards**. If it sounds like I'm doing something insane, please let me know, but that seems to be one [recommendation for bulk loading into postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/populate.html)

I use add_index and remove_index commands in migrations, but the same syntax doesn't work in a seeds.rb file. Is it possible to do this outside a migration in fact? (I'm imagining it might not be best practice, because it represents a schema change)

rails v2.3.8,
postgres v8.4.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is just to indulge in a little raw SQL within seeds.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DROP INDEX myindex ON mytable")
```

At 16 million records, I would recommend managing the whole thing via raw SQL (contained within seeds.rb if you like).  Do all 16 million records go into a single table?  There ought to be some PostgreSQL magic to bulk import a file (in a PostgreSQL specific format) into a table.

Comment: PostgreSQL's [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-copy.html) might be of use.

Comment: Thanks. I've used the raw SQL approach you've shown here.Yeah I was originally using COPY into a single table, but I'm moving to a two table (HABTM related models) set-up. I now need to set the parent id in one table as I'm loading.